# ReactiveUI, Version=3.2.0.0 assembly references issue

Tags: reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI 3.2.
When I run my app (WPF based), I see following log messages while the app seem to run as expected (including some expected ReactiveUI base features):

## Calling assembly : ReactiveUI, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Reactive.Windows.Threading, Version=1.1.11111.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WorkspaceSVSource
...
N/ZemaxAll/AppFx/trunk/Src/AppFxTestApp/bin/Debug/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WorkspaceSVN/AppFx/trunk/Src/AppFxTestApp/bin/Debug/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WorkspaceSVN/AppFx/trunk/Src/AppFxTestApp/bin/Debug/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WorkspaceSVN/AppFx/trunk/Src/AppFxTestApp/bin/Debug/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading/System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.EXE.

ERROR Logger: *** WPF Rx.NET DLL reference not added - using Event Loop *** 
ERROR Logger: Add a reference to System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll if you're using WPF / SL4 / WP7
ERROR Logger: or consider explicitly setting RxApp.DeferredScheduler if not

When I actually ad the reference to System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll, the log messages do not show up but all the ReactiveUI subscriptions stop working. Any ideas? What is a complete list of required extra references for ReactiveUI to work?

Comment: Do you possibly have logging misconfigured for RXUI? Or have an existing logging facility that RXUI is using by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be no such issue when upgraded to ReactiveUI v4.1. Thanks to the ReaciveUI team!